# Command + Delete (Move to Trash) command doesn't work

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, keyboard, shortcut, trash

I have this problem for a long time, and I don't know how to fix it. When I press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> key sequence, it doesn't work.

When I use the key sequence, I hear a beep.

It was working before I reinstalled macOS, but now it isn't. I can see the shortcut in menu, but I cannot use it via keyboard.

[image: when i select the file i can see the shortcut]

Comment: Are you able to delete the file by invoking the command from menu entry or by dragging the file into Trash?

Comment: Does it generate an error beep [you could test cmd/q in the Finder to make sure you're definitely hearing the beep, as that's invalid in Finder]

Comment: yes i hear a beep when i press CMD+DELETE

Comment: Just to be clear, you do have a _file_ or _folder_ selected when pressing **⌘⌫** and hearing the _beep_, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Check System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts to see if command-Delete was remapped to something, or to use Restore Defaults.

Answer (score -2):

This is by design. Apple doesn't want you to delete files, they want you to buy iCloud storage.